# sudo apt-get install package with python processing error

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, tor

So, I have tried to install tor and ffmpeg on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the step on: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian

but after I run the line : `apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring`

It produce this log of error:

```
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 178, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 136, in compile
    os.makedirs(dirname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 117] Structure needs cleaning: '/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__pycache__'
dpkg: error processing package python3.5-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.5:
 python3.5 depends on python3.5-minimal (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1); however:
  Package python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.5-dev:
 python3.5-dev depends on python3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1); however:
  Package python3.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.5-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3.5-dev (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5-minimal
 python3.5
 python3.5-dev
 python3-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do anyone know how to solve this? Thank You

Comment: what exactly did you execute before your got the error?

Comment: @Yaron sorry I have updated my question, I ran apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring which I followed from the instruction on the website

Comment: That doesn't look like the full output of the `apt-get` command. Also, are you sure you're on Ubuntu? Python 3.5 should be installed by default and if it isn't you either don't have Ubuntu or it's in a very bad state. It may be easier to reinstall from scratch.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes I am pretty sure i am using ubuntu, i will reinstall ubuntu and see if the problem persist